# Laravel model with multiple belongsToMany returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following situation...

There are users which belong to groups and there are games which belong to groups.

I try to get all the user's groups but it returns NULL.

I have the relations set up as follows:

User model:

```
public function groups(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_user');
}
```

Group model:

```
public function games(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'group_user');
}
```

group_user table

```
Schema::create('group_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('group_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now I try to get all the groups from a selected user

```
$user = User::find(1);

$userGroups = $user->groups;
```

So instead of $userGroups being all the groups of the user it's NULL
(there is an entry in the group_user table containing IDs)

Comment: if users belongsToMany groups than shouldn't groups hasMany users?

Comment: @chiliNUT Correct my if I'm wrong but that requires a user to have group_id which I want to avoid seeing users need have more than one group

Comment: Everything looks correct to me. What does `$user->groups()->get()` return?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You sir are my savior! Would you be able to explain to me why this is? Also, post it as a answer so i can flag it as correct ;)

Comment: So what does it return?

Comment: It returns the groups of the user that is selected by User::find()... Exactly what I needed.

Comment: So you probably have overridden the `$groups` property in the `User` model.

Comment: Could it be because the Game model has a groups function as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by: Paul Spiegel

```
$user->groups()->get()
```

Worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'group_user','user_id', 'group_id');
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried it, Paul Spiegel suggested `$user->groups()->get()` which worked. But thank you for your suggestion! :)